# I need to put text in a <h> that is in a Div that is in another Div that is with in another yet another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to put text in a `<h3>` that is in a Div that is in another Div that is with in another yet another div. So here is what it looks like:

```
 <div id="loginModal" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 193.8px;"><iframe hspace="0" src="/client/en_US/cntest/search/patronlogin/https:$002f$002farrowhead.ent.sirsi.net$002fclient$002fen_US$002fcntest$002fsearch$002faccount$003fdt$003dlist" name="dialog_iframeContent610" style="width:350px;height:215px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe></div>
   <iframe hspace="0" src="/client/en_US/cntest/search/patronlogin/https:$002f$002farrowhead.ent.sirsi.net$002fclient$002fen_US$002fcntest$002fsearch$002faccount$003fdt$003dlist" name="dialog_iframeContent610" style="width:350px;height:215px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
#document
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.0 strict//en" "http://www.w3.org
 /TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtlm1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/default.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/ctx/css/vse/css/Discovery_base.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/ctx/css/format-types.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/app/components/search/suggest.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/tapestry-console.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/t5-alerts.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/tree.css"><meta content="Apache Tapestry Framework (version 5.3.7)" name="generator"><script src="/client/assets/4.5.1/stack/en_US/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
 <body>
 <div class="content"><center>
 <div id="changePinDiv">
 <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">Change PIN</h3>
 <form onsubmit="javascript:return Tapestry.waitForPage(event);" action="/client/en_US/cntest/changepinplainpage.changepinpanel.changepinform?&amp;t:ac=HZWS/CN/region/$N/$N" method="post" id="changePinForm">
 <div class="" style="display: none;">
 <input value="HZWS/CN/region/$N/$N" name="t:ac" type="hidden">
 <input value="NeH4a76dR7kxhv6iIEnzIQ/wdgE=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAJ2QsUoDQRCGxwMhmE6wsFcQkY2FabQxBAThkIPDOsxtxsuGvd11d87ExsqXsPEJxEqfIIWd7+AD2FhYWbg5CwVB0WZYPmbn+/lvnmFxImCrP0JTUqZMpjEOLGlXNsgp49CQFuNBHcgbrCh46FpfCnQoRyQYHQX2510hrSetClFgINErIkTJB4r0cC0nrt368az9tPLwlsBCCm1pDXurj+JFhuV0jGfY0VHZydkrU+5NHcPSp/UfKXt/TZl5KymEvC4qFYKyZnY73Dl5vX5MAKZusgkbvycI888c7fs/2qWtnDVkOIhGx9/lV/nL6v3dZT+BJIWW1CpuHw5P4aKpjzRVEczra9C8rtaHfLD95fkOfeiN7OIBAAA=" name="t:formdata" type="hidden">
 </div>
 <table><tbody><tr><td><label for="j_username" class="username">Barcode</label>:</td><td><input maxlength="30" class="user_name_input" id="j_username" name="j_username" type="TextField"><img id="j_username_icon" class="t-error-icon" alt="" src="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/spacer.gif" style="display: none;"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input value="Submit" class="loginButton" id="submit_0" name="submit_0" type="submit"></td></tr></tbody></table>
 </form>
 </div>
 </center>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">Tapestry.onDOMLoaded(function() {
Tapestry.init({"formEventManager":[{"formId":"changePinForm","validate":{"submit":true,"blur":true}}]});
Tapestry.init({"activate":["j_username"],"validate":[{"j_username":[["required","Barcode is a required field."]]}]});
});
</script></body></html>
```

I hope i loaded that correctly. The section I need to change the text on is in the "div id="changePinDiv"" and in that div there is an `<h3>` that has the text I would like to change. Any time I try to do it via CSS it does not take.

Here is what I have tried

```
#changePinDiv:before{
content:"You must have an email address assigned to your account.";
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

I have even tried

```
#changePinDiv.h3:before{
 content:"You must have an email address assigned to your account.";
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Not sure what else to do. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just put the text in the `<h3>`? Why do you have to do it in CSS?

Comment: This is a html that is not editable from my side. Because this is a service that we use and can only edit the CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject content via CSS into your `<h3>` the style would be this:

```
#changePinDiv h3:before{
     content:"You must have an email address assigned to your account.";
     font-size:10px;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

But that would produce an `<h3>` that would look like this:

```
<h3>You must have an email address assigned to your account.Change Pin</h3>
```

It might make more since to place this content `:after` and include a space:

```
#changePinDiv h3:after{
     content:" You must have an email address assigned to your account.";
     font-size:10px;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnLhxmbk/)

Or you could have the content go to a new line like this:

```
#changePinDiv h3:after{
     content:"You must have an email address assigned to your account.";
     display: block;
     font-size:10px;
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nnLhxmbk/2/)

**Update**

Since its an iframe, if its hosted on your domain you can use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#changePinDiv h3").append(" You must have an email address assigned to your account.");
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not take either. It is really odd that it will not take.

Comment: do any other styles take? Like can you add this: `#changePinDiv { background-color: red; }`. you can see it works in the fiddle, so the problem is with your environment probably

Comment: Is this content in an `<iframe>`? You can not apply CSS to HTML that is loaded in an iframe

Comment: I'm going to say it is an issue that I will not be able to fix. because that didn't work either. I stated to someone else that this is a service that we can only edit the CSS and JS for the company that owns the service will not let us edit the actual html and they do not give much info on how to change really embedded items like this.

Comment: @McNile83 You can only edit contents of an iframe that is on your domain because of the same origin policy.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I will have to come up with another way then.

Comment: @McNile83 You can try the update I posted if the iframe is host on your domain

Comment: I tired it but nope it didn't go. we don't host the actual site so that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be done through CSS?

If not, maybe try using JQuery! It is fairly standardized among web developers, and worth learning. By using it, you could target target the div like this `$('#changePinDiv').text('You must have an email address assigned to your account.')`

You could also tie that to many different events (click events, document ready, etc)

Comment: I have tried to use JQuery and it will not work. I am not sure why. The only thing that I can think of is that the iFrame that this is in doesn't use JQuery. this is what we tried $('#changePinDiv').append("You must have an email in your library account to reset a new pin, otherwise call your home library during business hours.")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can use this piece of jQuery:

```js
$('#changePinDiv').prepend('You must have an email address assigned to your account');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <center>
      <div id="changePinDiv">
        <h3 style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">Change PIN</h3>
        <form onsubmit="javascript:return Tapestry.waitForPage(event);" action="/client/en_US/cntest/changepinplainpage.changepinpanel.changepinform?&amp;t:ac=HZWS/CN/region/$N/$N" method="post" id="changePinForm">
          <div class="" style="display: none;">
            <input value="HZWS/CN/region/$N/$N" name="t:ac" type="hidden">
            <input value="NeH4a76dR7kxhv6iIEnzIQ/wdgE=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAJ2QsUoDQRCGxwMhmE6wsFcQkY2FabQxBAThkIPDOsxtxsuGvd11d87ExsqXsPEJxEqfIIWd7+AD2FhYWbg5CwVB0WZYPmbn+/lvnmFxImCrP0JTUqZMpjEOLGlXNsgp49CQFuNBHcgbrCh46FpfCnQoRyQYHQX2510hrSetClFgINErIkTJB4r0cC0nrt368az9tPLwlsBCCm1pDXurj+JFhuV0jGfY0VHZydkrU+5NHcPSp/UfKXt/TZl5KymEvC4qFYKyZnY73Dl5vX5MAKZusgkbvycI888c7fs/2qWtnDVkOIhGx9/lV/nL6v3dZT+BJIWW1CpuHw5P4aKpjzRVEczra9C8rtaHfLD95fkOfeiN7OIBAAA="
              name="t:formdata" type="hidden">
          </div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="j_username" class="username">Barcode</label>:</td>
                <td><input maxlength="30" class="user_name_input" id="j_username" name="j_username" type="TextField"><img id="j_username_icon" class="t-error-icon" alt="" src="/client/assets/4.5.1/core/spacer.gif" style="display: none;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input value="Submit" class="loginButton" id="submit_0" name="submit_0" type="submit"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
```